# Proving that $\sum_{j=0}^n 2^j=2^{n+1}-1$ for $n\geq 0$ by induction

Tags: induction, factoring

Solving $S=$ $\displaystyle \sum_{j=0}^n$ $2$$^j$ = $2$$^n$$^+$$^1$ $-1$

So I was able to find  the basis and the the RHS but I'm not sure how I should go about solving the LHS. Since I have K+1 in the sigma

Solving  $2$$^K$$^+$$^1$ $-1$ +  $\displaystyle \sum_{j=0}^{n+1}2^j$ = $2$$^K$$^+$$^2$ $-1$

Answer (score 2):

See if you can follow the meat of the induction proof below (getting from the LHS to the RHS):
\begin{align}
\sum_{j=0}^{k+1}2^j &= \sum_{j=0}^k 2^j+2^{k+1}\tag{by defn. of $\Sigma$}\\[0.5em]
&= (2^{k+1}-1)+2^{k+1}\tag{by inductive hypothesis}\\[0.5em]
&= 2\cdot2^{k+1}-1\tag{group like terms}\\[0.5em]
&= 2^{k+2}-1\tag{exponent law}\\[0.5em]
&= 2^{(k+1)+1}-1.\tag{simplify}
\end{align}